# getaddrinfo hung for 5 seconds with IPv6 enabled before trying 2nd DNS server

Tags: dns, ipv6, glibc

In my env with glibc 2.28, DNS query will send out A and AAAA query simultaneously. This is normal.
In some special case, only A query is sent out, but it stuck till 5s timeout before trying the next DNS servers. After 5s, it triggers both A and AAAA query to 2nd DNS. this causes the DNS query delay.

```
|Time     | 192.168.1.1                         | 192.172.47.208                         |
|         |                   | 192.31.0.72       |                   | 129.94.88.140       |                   
|         |(53960)  <------------------  (53)     |                   |                   |
|2023-10-11 23:23:29.867129457|         Standard query 0xd11          |                   |                   |DNS: Standard query 0xd119 A abcdef.com
|         |(40606)  ------------------>  (53)     |                   |                   |
|2023-10-11 23:23:29.907789682|         Standard query respo          |                   |                   |DNS: Standard query response 0xd119 Refused A abcdef.com
|         |(40606)  <------------------  (53)     |                   |                   |
|2023-10-11 23:23:34.871853446|                   |                   |         Standard query 0xd11          |DNS: Standard query 0xd119 A abcdef.com
|         |                   |                   |(52553)  ------------------>  (53)     |
|2023-10-11 23:23:34.910733469|                   |                   |         Standard query respo          |DNS: Standard query response 0xd119 A abcdef.com A 192.168.33.2
|         |                   |                   |(52553)  <------------------  (53)     |
|2023-10-11 23:23:34.910792733|                   |                   |         Standard query 0xc81          |DNS: Standard query 0xc81e AAAA abcdef.com
|         |                   |                   |(60841)  ------------------>  (53)     |
|2023-10-11 23:23:34.949666033|                   |                   |         Standard query respo          |DNS: Standard query response 0xc81e AAAA abcdef.com
|         |                   |                   |(60841)  <------------------  (53)     |
```

Try to reproduce, but no clue what conditoin trigger this issue.